# ¿Cómo puedo tomar información de excel en python y guardarla en arreglos?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Mi problema está en que cuando leo la información de excel no encuentro la manera de guardar las filas de excel en arreglos. He intentado leer con ayuda de pandas y luego con ayuda de openpyxl pero en los dos casos quedo corto de conocimiento para seguir con el procedimiento de tomar y guardar la información en los arreglos.

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.ExcelFile('Libro1.xlsx')
df = data.parse('Hoja1')
```

Este es el código que utilizo para leer el archivo con pandas y lo hace perfectamente, mi problema está cuando trato de tomar una fila del df y guardarla en un arreglo.

Espero que mi problema esté claro. Gracias de antemano por su ayuda.

Comment: Tanto Pandas ([`pandas.read_excel`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.20/generated/pandas.read_excel.html)) como openpyxl pueden leer archivos xlsx sin problemas. Si vas a trabajar y operar con datos tabulados usa Pandas sin duda, por eficiencia y comodidad. Si mostraras el codigo con el que  intentas leer el archivo y los problemas que te surgen podríamos ayudarte correctamente. Un saludo.

Comment: Voy a crear una respuesta usando Pandas Alejandro, Lo normal y correcto seria que trabajaras y operaras con los datos usando Pandas. No obstante, ¿con arrays quieres decir listas de Python o usas arrays de NumPy?

Comment: Lo que debo hacer es calcular distancias euclidianas entre dos arrays, sinceramente no sé cómo será mejor manejarlo. Si con listas de python o arrays de numpy. Agradezco tu interés.

Comment: Usa pandas/numpy si puedes, las listas serán mucho más lentas. Además el código será mas complejo incluso. El ejemplo que dabas de xlsx tenía cuatro columnas ¿son las coordenadas de los puntos x e y,  x1, x2, y1, y2 por casualidad? Lo digo por darte un ejemplo con pandas de como calcular la distancia euclidiana porque es una línea de código.

Comment: Cada fila la tomaría como un vector, entonces calculo la distancia euclidiana entre dos vectores, solo que el ejercicio inicial que tengo es calcular la similitud máxima entre la información que tengo en excel (los vectores donde cada vector es una fila) y un vector dado por un usuario

Answer (score 3):

Como te he comentado puedes leer archivos xlsx en pandas sin problemas. Lo más simple es usar el método [`pandas.read_excel`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.20/generated/pandas.read_excel.html). Ya que lees con pandas lo lógico es que operes también con Pandas y aproveches su potencial y el de NumPy. Si vas a trabajar con vectores y a realizar cálculos numéricos importantes como comentas te aconsejo desechar las listas y no salirte de Pandas/Numpy y otras bibliotecas de cálculo como SciPy, SymPy, etc.

Si lo deseas no obstante, puedes pasar el dataframe a un array de NumPy o a una lista de listas sin problemas. Vamos a partir del ejemplo que dabas:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Para leer la `Hoja1` de `libro1.xlsx` hacemos:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.read_excel("libro1.xlsx", sheetname='Hoja1',  header=None)
```

Es importante definir el header como `None` o darle una lista con los nombres que queramos darles a nuestras columnas. Esto es así, porque por defecto toma la primera fila de la hoja como header para nombrar las columnas, dado que se supone que tu excel no lo tiene (la primera fila son datos) debes hace esto.

Con esto obtenemos nuestro DataFrame:

```
>>> df
     0   1  2   3
0    5   3  1   8
1    6   3  9   5
2    5   5  0   9
3    3   5  1  11
4    7   1  5  12
5    1   3  6   8
6    0   5  6   5
7    8   5  2   7
8   10   3  8   6
9    3   2  4   8
10   3  15  7   8
11   4   5  2   5
12   3   3  3   7
13   7   4  6  10
14   5   8  3   8
15  12  13  3  14
```

La primera columna y la primera fila son los índices por defecto de las filas y los nombres de las columnas, y puedes usarlos para obtener una fila mediante `df.iloc[indice]`:

```
>>> df.iloc[0]
0    5
1    3
2    1
3    8
```

Obtener un array de Numpy:

```
>>> df.iloc[0].values
array([5, 3, 1, 8])
```

O una lista:

```
>>> df.iloc[0].values.tolist()
    [5, 3, 1, 8]
```

Puedes hacer esto de una sola vez y obtener un array de dos dimensiones de NumPy o una lista de listas de Python:

```
>>> np_array = df.values
>>> np_array
array([[ 5,  3,  1,  8],
       [ 6,  3,  9,  5],
       [ 5,  5,  0,  9],
       [ 3,  5,  1, 11],
       [ 7,  1,  5, 12],
       [ 1,  3,  6,  8],
       [ 0,  5,  6,  5],
       [ 8,  5,  2,  7],
       [10,  3,  8,  6],
       [ 3,  2,  4,  8],
       [ 3, 15,  7,  8],
       [ 4,  5,  2,  5],
       [ 3,  3,  3,  7],
       [ 7,  4,  6, 10],
       [ 5,  8,  3,  8],
       [12, 13,  3, 14]])



>>> matriz_listas = df.values.tolist()
>>> matriz_listas
[[5, 3, 1, 8],  [6, 3, 9, 5],  [5, 5, 0, 9],  [3, 5, 1, 11],
 [7, 1, 5, 12], [1, 3, 6, 8],  [0, 5, 6, 5],  [8, 5, 2, 7],
 [10, 3, 8, 6], [3, 2, 4, 8],  [3, 15, 7, 8], [4, 5, 2, 5],
 [3, 3, 3, 7],  [7, 4, 6, 10], [5, 8, 3, 8],  [12, 13, 3, 14]]
```

Los cuales puedes iterar o acceder por índice para obtener las filas:

```
>>> np_array[1]
array([6, 3, 9, 5])

>>> matriz_listas[1]
[6, 3, 9, 5]
```

Comment: ¿Cómo convertiría todo en un array de dos dimensiones de numpy?  Gracias por tu ayuda, ha sido muy útil

Comment: Ups!!! Perdón @AlejandroBuitragoDuque me salté esa línea, voy a editar la respuesta.... :(. Es simplemente `np_array = df.values`

Answer (score 1):

Lo *más* importante es que guardes el **documento de excel** como `.csv`. De esta forma le dices que guarde los datos separados por `;` lo cual se indica en el campo `sep` (separator). Otro punto es que pongas `header=None` para que no tome la primera fila como datos útiles.

```
import pandas as pd
test_csv = 'test.csv'
matriz = pd.read_csv(test_csv, sep=';', header=None)
print(matriz)
```

Utilizando este código con un excel `test.csv` que contiene una matriz 3x3 con los número del 1 al 9 la impresión por pantalla es:

```
   0  1  2
0  1  2  3
1  4  5  6
2  7  8  9
[Finished in 0.4s]
```

La primera fila y la primera columna indican los índices de los elementos de la matriz.

Espero que te sirva de ayuda ;)

Comment: ¿Y cómo podría tomar la fila 0 y guardarla en un array? @mbayon

Comment: generalmente la fila cero es donde esta el header, los nombres de los campos

Comment: @AlejandroBuitragoDuque La notación para seleccionar la primera fila de un array es `matriz[:1]`. Asignas eso a una nueva variable y ahí tienes la primera fila separada.